# NIntegrate: how to obtain a more precise plot

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I want to plot a function involving the integral

```
a = 20;
d = 10^(-1);

int[t_]:= NIntegrate[E^(-w/a) Sin[(w-d)t]/(w-d)^2,{w,0,d,∞},Method->"PrincipalValue"]

Plot[int[t],{t,0,1000]
```

Ideally the plot should show damped perfect oscillations. But because of the numerical method of integration, the oscillations are not symmetric:

[image]

How can I obtain a more precise plot having perfect osccilations?

Comment: Your code gives an error message when evaluated. Extra parenthesis. And I do not think I have all the information needed to evaluate it myself either way. In any event, have you tried increasing `PlotPoints`?

Comment: @user6014 I corrected the code. I did not try that. I thought that the problem is more related to how precise is the integration method rather than the number of points.

Comment: how did you correct it? It still does not return an output on my machine (11.2 Windows)

Comment: @user6014 Try it now. Note that the image in the post is the result of a more complicated function involving the integral. I just provided a working example.

Comment: Please, `Quit` your kernel and run your code before you post it here for other people to try and run. There are still errors, I think you're still missing brackets. People will be much less likely to help if they have to repeatedly jump through hoops just to look at the problem.

Comment: You can specify a large `PlotPoints`, try `PlotPoints->1000`  . It will be horribly slow i suspect

Comment: This took 51 seconds to evaluate on my machine, `AbsoluteTiming[
 plot = ListPlot[Table[int[t], {t, 0, 1000}], Joined -> True];]`, which only finds 1000 values. Plot is going to look for many more than 1000, and increasing `PlotPoints` will look for many, many more than 1000. Those are relatively long evaluations.

Comment: Believe it or not this integral can be done analytically.  Sorry I don't have time to work it up right now.(Treat the part around the singularity separately).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is how I did that integral analytically, with a bit of manual manipulation to take care of the principal value:

```
a = 20;
d = 10^(-1);
With[{t = 100}, 
     NIntegrate[E^(-w/a) Sin[(w - d) t]/(w - d)^2, {w, 0, d, \[Infinity]},
       Method -> "PrincipalValue"]]
```

> -1.05077

There are a bunch of steps to get here, in a nutshell break the integral into three parts `{0,d} , {d, 2d} , {2 d,Inf}` , do a variable substitution to make the second interval also `{0,d}` and add the first two integrands together, which eliminates the singularity.

```
    intinf =
     Integrate[E^(-w/a) Sin[(w - d) t]/(w - d)^2, {w, 2 d, \[Infinity]}, 
        Assumptions -> {t > 0, d > 0, a > 0}] +
     Integrate[
        Sin[w t]/w^2 (E^(-(w + d)/a) - E^((w - d)/a) ), {w, 0, d}, 
        Assumptions -> {t > 0, d > 0, a > 0}] // FullSimplify 
    % /. t -> 100 // N
```

> (-2 (I + 20 t) ExpIntegralEi[1/200 - (I t)/10] + 
>    800 E^(1/200) Sin[t/10] - 
>    2 (-I + 20 t) (CoshIntegral[1/200 + (I t)/10] + 
>       SinhIntegral[1/200 + (I t)/10]))/(80 E^(1/200))
>
> -1.05077 + 0. I

note I expect this should work as well with `a` and `d` symbolic but it will take much longer to evaluate the integral.

```
Plot[Chop@int, {t, 0, 1000}, PlotRange -> {-3, 6}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I would turn your integral into an ODE. Here is an inactive form of your integral:

```
a = 20;
d = 1/10;
integral = Inactive[Integrate][
    Exp[-w/a] Sin[(w-d)t]/(w-d)^2,
    {w, 0, ∞},
    GenerateConditions->False
]
```

> Inactive[Integrate][(E^(-w/20) Sin[t (-(1/10) + w)])/(-(1/10) + w)^2, {w, 0, ∞}, GenerateConditions -> False]

Let's take 2 derivatives with respect to `t`, and activate:

```
Activate @ D[integral, {t, 2}]
```

> (20 (-20 t Cos[t/10] + Sin[t/10]))/(1 + 400 t^2)

That's enough information to create the differential equation, now we need to come up with initial conditions:

```
Activate[integral /. t->0]
Activate[D[integral, t] /. t->0]
```

> 0
>
> -((I π + ExpIntegralEi[1/200])/E^(1/200))

We see that the first derivative is complex. However, this is because `integral` is divergent, and needs regularization to be evaluated. So, it is actually the real part that is needed. Now, we can solve the ODE:

```
if = NDSolveValue[
    {
    f''[t] == Activate @ D[integral, {t, 2}],
    f[0] == 0,
    f'[0] == Re @ Activate[D[integral, t] /. t->0]
    },
    f,
    {t, 0, 1000}
];
```

Plotting this solution is fast:

```
Plot[if[t], {t, 0, 1000}, PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

Let's compare it to plotting your `int` function:

```
p1 = Plot[int[t], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange->All]; //AbsoluteTiming
p2 = Plot[if[t], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange->All]; //AbsoluteTiming

p1
p2
```

> {19.7421, Null}
>
> {0.054623, Null}

[image]

Finally, as @george2079 says, it is possible to find the integral analytically. One method is to use [`DSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveValue):

```
DSolveValue[
    {
    f''[t] == Activate@D[integral, {t, 2}],
    f[0] == 0,
    f'[0] == Re @ Activate[D[integral, t] /. t->0]
    },
    f,
    t
]
```

> Function[{t}, (1/(
>    200 E^(1/200)))(-200 E^(1/200) t + 200 t Cosh[1/200] + 
>      200 t CosIntegral[I/200] + 5 I CosIntegral[I/200 - t/10] - 
>      100 t CosIntegral[I/200 - t/10] - 5 I CosIntegral[I/200 + t/10] - 
>      100 t CosIntegral[I/200 + t/10] - 200 t ExpIntegralEi[1/200] + 
>      2000 E^(1/200) Sin[t/10] + t Sinc[I/200] + 200 t SinhIntegral[1/200] + 
>      5 SinIntegral[I/200 - t/10] + 100 I t SinIntegral[I/200 - t/10] - 
>      5 SinIntegral[I/200 + t/10] + 100 I t SinIntegral[I/200 + t/10])]